# How to display requests from typescript file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm a beginner in typescript and react. I am trying to display the title value from my requests api file. I tried making a response Interface, but I'm not sure where to go from there

requests.ts

```
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY
export default {
  fetchTrending: {
    title: "Trending Movies",
    url: `/trendingmovies?api_key=${API_KEY}`
  },
}

export iterface MyRes{
  title: string,
  url:string,
  key: number 
}
```

NavBar.tsx

```
import request, {MyRes} from "requests"

function NavBar() {
  return(
    <nav>
      <div>

      </div>
    </nav>
  )
)
export default NavBar;
```

Comment: [How to Fetch Data in React](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fetch-data-react/)

Comment: More powerfull and advanced solution is to use an Express JS - https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api